# couchbase server not return id within record using c# code

Tags: c#, couchbase, couchbase-view, couchbase-sync-gateway

when we get records from couchbase server using select query not get id of each record

my code below . what i am missing

```
        var clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfiguration.Servers = new List<Uri> { new Uri("http://localhost:8091/pools/") };

        List<string> objDocList = new List<string>();
        Cluster Cluster = new Cluster(clientConfiguration);
        var bucket = Cluster.OpenBucket();
        var result = bucket.Query<dynamic>("select * from testbucket");


        foreach (var row in result)
        {

                dynamic propJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(row);

       //propJSON not contain id

        }
```

I want id for updating record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [meta](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/metafun.html) function to return the id

```
select meta(tb).id, tb.* from testbucket tb
```

Comment: ok its working but manually added record in couchbase server not getting record using query

Comment: I want also get rev in this select query

Comment: I am using cas value for updating the documents is it correct

Comment: It depends of your needs. CAS is used to manage concurrency. You can find a first documentation [here](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/dotnet-2.2/check-and-swap.html)

Comment: ok thanks, but i want to update document so on which basis i update

Comment: Use `Upsert` method. If you use the .Net SDK the documenation is [here](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-net-client-2.2.8/)

Comment: but this upsert directly update document on server(i don't want to directely update on server) but i want to update on couchbase lite then i start pull push replication

Comment: If you use couchbase lite the documentation with examples is [here](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/document/index.html)

Comment: using MapDelegate to pass condition and execute query on couchbase lite

Comment: MapDelegate labelsMapDelegate = (doc, emit) =>
            {

                if (doc["passtId"] == "f3d3")

                {
                    emit(string.Concat(doc["createdDate"], doc["_id"]), doc);
                }
            };

 var assetsDocsView = db.GetView("Acb");

                assetsDocsView.SetMap(labelsMapDelegate, "1");

                var query = assetsDocsView.CreateQuery();


               var rows = query.Run();



This code returns all the documents but i want only matching condition in Mapdeligate. please tell me what i miss